Why does Luna Haruna use the を particle here?
In the song snowdrop, she says:

今日を笑いながら、しあわせだと明日はきっと呼べるように。

Is 今日 simply the object or is she marking time with this particle somehow?

Here are the original lyrics, with original line breaks preserved:

すごく　もどかしくて
すこし　背伸びした　今日を
笑いながら　しあわせだと
明日は　きっと　呼べるように

So this を seems to be part of the A​をBと呼ぶ ("call A B") construction. The word order is indeed tricky, but in normal word order, the sentence is:

明日はきっと笑いながら、今日をしあわせだと呼べるように(なりたい)。
(literally) Tomorrow, I hope to be able to call today "happiness" while laughing.
(すごくもどかしくてすこし背伸びした modifies 今日 as a relative clause, but this part has been omitted.)

From the first part of the song, we can see that the narrator has felt regret and slight confusion about her current situation. However, she hopes that even such feelings will be recalled as happy memories in the future.
